# WD My Book Live: Remote Access on local network only

Tags: networking, hard-drive

MyBookLive 2TB  Firmware version: 02.43.03-022

I would like to use the WD My Cloud mobile app to access my files but only when I am on the same local network as the MBL itself. In other words, I do not want to access it over the Internet. I am pretty sure I used to be able to do this in prior versions of the iOS app. I simply turned off Remote Access on the Settings page but the iOS app was able to connect when I was at home. But after a recent update, it pops up a box saying remote access is disabled.

Has anyone else seen this? Is there a way to restrict remote access to just the local network?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you're on the same network you can access it via any kind of file browser. I'm not sure about iOS but for android file explorers like [ES Explorer](http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.estrongs.android.pop&hl=en_GB) will let you browse when you're on the same network (as you would on a pc). You could then turn off the remote access completely.

A quick search found [this](https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/fileexplorer/id499470113?mt=8) which seems to do the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable "Enable" option in the Remote Access tab in the "dashboard" for the device. Beware that some unrelated operation oftentimes tunrs this back on without letting you know. This is really annoying, and I couldn't find any reference how to completely disable remote access.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please read the question again carefully. Your answer does **not** answer the original question.